installing the mvn package (dspace 6)
Can you help me fix this error when installing the mvn package (dspace 6)?
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project solr: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.dspace.modules:solr:war:6.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.dspace:dspace-solr:jar:classes:6.0 -> org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:4.10.4 -> org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.1.1:

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.
